# Mysql array values repeated in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query where output from unique option getting repeated in while loop belp query with mysql dump

```
CREATE TABLE `txt` (
      `option` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `txt` VALUES ('a', 'ashok');
INSERT INTO `txt` VALUES ('a', 'sachin');
INSERT INTO `txt` VALUES ('b', 'parvez');
query:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT option, name from txt");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $option = $row['option'];
 $name   = $row['username'];
 $array[$option] = $name;
}

print_r($array);
```

Actual output:

```
Array ( [a] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ashok [1] => sachin ) 
Array ( [b] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ashok [1] => sachin [2] => parvez)
```

Expected output:

```
Array ( [a] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ashok [1] => sachin )
Array ( [b] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => parvez)
```

Please tell me what mistake I have made in this query

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code? Because the output of this code woudn't match the actual output you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not produce the result you claim it does under "actual" at all. You keep overwriting `$array[$option]` in the loop while what you want to do is add the value to the array.

Nevertheless, following code will produce the result you name under "expected":

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `option`, `username` from `txt`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $option = $row['option'];
    $name   = $row['username'];
    $array[$option]['name'][] = $name;
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ashok
                    [1] => sachin
                )
        )
    [b] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => parvez
                )
        )
)
```